# NuScenes Dataset : How to project lidar pointcloud into camera image plane?

Tags: camera, dataset, projection, lidar

I need to use a multimodal dataset in order to detect objects for an autonomous vehicle project.

The NuScenes Dataset just came with a lot of data : https://www.nuscenes.org/. Did anyone know how to project the lidar pointcloud into camera image plane with projection matrix just like for the Kitti Dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the official nuscenes SDK and the function `map_pointcloud_to_image`.
I believe, it does exactly what you have in mind.

https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit/blob/master/python-sdk/nuscenes/nuscenes.py

Answer (score 0):

You can call the map_pointcloud_to_image function by creating an instance of NuSceneseExplorer.

from nuscenes import NuScenesExplorer